# How to install pybrain

Tags: python, python-3.x, pybrain

I am attempting to install pybrains but I am getting this error:

```
C:\Python34\python.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm         Community Edition 4.0.4\helpers\pycharm\pycharm_setup_runner.py" C:\Users\PycharmProjects\Youtube\pybrain-pybrain-87c7ac3\setup.py
Testing started at 14:08 ...
running pycharm_test
running egg_info
writing PyBrain.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to PyBrain.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to PyBrain.egg-info\top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'PyBrain.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'PyBrain.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition     4.0.4\helpers\pycharm\pycharm_setup_runner.py", line 26, in <module>
    exec (fh.read(), globals(), locals())
  File "<string>", line 21, in <module>
  File "C:\PYTHON34\LIB\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\PYTHON34\LIB\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\PYTHON34\LIB\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\test.py", line     138, in run
    self.with_project_on_sys_path(self.run_tests)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\test.py", line     118, in with_project_on_sys_path
    func()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition         4.0.4\helpers\pycharm\pycharm_commands\pycharm_test.py",         line 18, in run_tests
    testLoader=loader_class()
  File "C:\PYTHON34\LIB\unittest\main.py", line 92, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "C:\PYTHON34\LIB\unittest\main.py", line 139, in parseArgs
    self.createTests()
  File "C:\PYTHON34\LIB\unittest\main.py", line 146, in createTests
    self.module)
  File "C:\PYTHON34\LIB\unittest\loader.py", line 146, in     loadTestsFromNames
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "C:\PYTHON34\LIB\unittest\loader.py", line 146, in <listcomp>
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "C:\PYTHON34\LIB\unittest\loader.py", line 105, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__('.'.join(parts_copy))
  File "c:\users\dhowarth\pycharmprojects\youtube\pybrain-pybrain-87c7ac3\pybrain\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from structure.__init__ import *
ImportError: No module named 'structure'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Where do I find the 'Structure' module?

Anyone having the same issue?

I have followed the instructions on: https://github.com/pybrain/pybrain/wiki/installation.

what am I missing?

Comment: You have to install pybrain with python 2.7. You are currently using 3.4

Comment: @404pio Not quite. I am using Pybrain on Python 3.7.5 and it works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

The Pybrain can be setup by `pip install pybrain` directly.

The FNN in pybrain have a bit problem of convergence and performance. As substitution, there are lots of advices on [Python for AI](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonForArtificialIntelligence), such as FANN ([An example](http://jansipke.nl/using-fann-with-python/)) and scikit-learn (for lots of ML method but not contains FNN directly).

Answer (score 1):

Try not to use `pip`. I always prefer getting the entire folder from PyPI or github (if available) and then doing the simple `python setup.py install`.

Also, whenever you do some work with the packages which are under active development (or not very commonly use), please read their documentation.

If you see the documentation : [Here](https://cloud.github.com/downloads/pybrain/pybrain/Documentation_0.3.pdf). You will see that they use Python 2.x.
And you are clearly using Python 3.x.

Get Python 2.x and download the folder from [github](https://github.com/pybrain/pybrain). Unzip it and install.

Hope it helps.

Cheers.

Comment: I am using Pybrain on Python 3.7.5 and it works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Try following queries:

1. `pip install numpy`
2. `pip install scipy`
3. `pip install pybrain`

**OR:**

download [ez_setup.py](http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py) and run it:

```
python ez_setup.py
```

**OR:**

use easy_install:

```
easy_install pybrain
```